# SOAP request - SAS CI

Tags: sas

Am trying to invoke campaign via SOAP request ,which is  suppose to insert data into data warehouse,but it's not happening.am using DS2 code for it
When I try run the same campaign in test mode in SAS CI it's happening

I want the log that gets generated via SOAP request.can anyone let me know the path for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is about the SAS Customer Intelligence product, correct? If you don't get a response here, you might try over at https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Customer-Intelligence/bd-p/sas_ci .  As written I don't think this meets the stack overflow guidelines for questions, i.e. it's not clear that it's a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the log files on your application & mid-tier servers. Search the log files for the time you ran your request.

Start by checking the ObjectSpawner log to see if any connections were made the SAS environment at that time: ex. C:\SASHome\Lev1\ObjectSpawner\Logs